# MediaStyle Notification not working properly

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create a MediaStyle Notification. I followed [the  official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#mediastyle-notifications)  but I am facing some problems.

The notification is shown when I am starting the playback service as a foreground but

1. the play/pause button does nothing
2. the content activity is not shown if you click the notification
3. the playback service is not stopped when a swipe gesture happens

How can I solve this? Here is [my MediaBrowserServiceCompat class](https://github.com/tomasmichael995/GreekPodcasts/blob/changed_pojos/app/src/main/java/gr/kalymnos/sk3m3l10/greekpodcasts/media_playing_service/MediaPlaybackService.java). The notification is shown via `showNotification()` in `onPlay()`.

Comment: @Themellis Have you got any solution for setcontentIntent?

Comment: Can't remember bro, it has been two years :) @SARATHV